# Python Discord Bot - missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, discord

[My cog that has all the command classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60KjK.png)

Using a youtube guide i made a load, unload and reload a cog function. I would like to know if its possible to put those functions in cogs themselves.
Right now i get an error, when i try to use the !unload command

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvFr.png)

[Main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieADy.png)

Comment: [Please don't upload code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Change (ctx, extension) to (self, ctx, extension)